# Office web apps unattended server installation

Tags: installation, sharepoint-2013, office-web-components

Our IT-department wants a script for everything that should be installed on any of our servers. They don't want to use installation wizards and click next-next-next (don't ask me why)

We need to install [Office Web Apps Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35489) to be used with our SharePoint 2013 solution.
Is it possible to install this without having to use the wizard? (with a script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Office Web Apps server folders, there is a folder called Files\setupsilent\ where you will find config.xml. this file contain information about silent installation of Office Web Apps Server.

call the installer like this (if your Office Web Apps server installer is extracted in c:\OWA)
setup.exe /config files\setupsilent\config.xml

this will be complete silent setup. You will not see any screens. If you like to see wizard and progress bar proceeding automatically (passive), you can change the 
"Display Level="none" in this config.xml 
to
Display Level="basic"

hope it helps.